# how does == operator in java works for primitive types

Tags: java

I was reading about == operator and I noticed it says it is used for reference comparison. But then how does it work when we have a condition like

```java
int i = 5;
if (i == 5){
    .....
}
```

i being int primitive type.

Does it gets converted to Integer wrapper class behind the scene and the It behaves like strings immutable class meaning even if we hard code value it will point to the same object in memory?

Comment: Primitives are not Objects.  They are treated differently.

Comment: In advanced to the comment above:
Objects are generated at the heap of your memory. They are compared by it's memory address reference by default. For primitive types it is different since they are not heap objects they are compared by their value

Answer (score 2):

This operator is actually the 'primitive' comparison that exists on machine language level. To compare two values, load one of them into a CPU register, then subtract the other value and see if all bits are zero.

This comparison works for boolean, numbers, characters - anything you can put into a memory location that is not bigger than the CPUs register. In Java such data types are called primitive types. Today most machines have 64 bits which is the magic size limitation.

Since Objects and Arrays can easily exceed that given size, a pointer to their memory location is passed instead. The primitive comparison would now compare two Objects by comparing their memory pointers. But it is not smart enough to compare the Object content.

So if you have two Objects in different addresses that both have the same value the `==` comparison will fail, although most people think the result should be true. That's why Java has both == operator and the .equals method.